# How to assign the value of variable to a texbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The variable is defined as pedateXX and textbox name is pedatein and is hidden, see below.
I have tried using getElementById, but after checking pedatein, it contains a null value.

```
var pedateIn = document.getElementById('pedateXX')

<input type="hidden" name="pedatein" id="pedatein" size="8" maxlength="8" value=/%pedatein%/ autocomplete=OFF/>
```

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML? The code looks fine to me if the ID is correct

Comment: Do you want the textbox to get the value of the variable? or the variable to get the value of what is inside the textbox?

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is `pedateXX` then you want.

```
document.getElementById('pedatein').value = pedateXX;
```

Comment: var pedateIn = document.getElementById('pedateXX')
    
    <input type="hidden" name="pedatein" id="pedatein" size="8" maxlength="8" value=/%pedatein%/ autocomplete=OFF/>

Comment: Thanks to all who provided solutions. I am new at this so if missed anyone, I apoloize.

Comment: @ReneChavez. you need tick the answer, which helped

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign the value like in this example:

```
document.getElementById('pedateXX').value = pedateIn;
```

Comment: Thanks to all who provided solutions. I am new at this so if missed anyone, I apoloize